# Image resizing from a database with PHP

Tags: database, image, resize-image

I currently have a script which will pull in image contents from a database and, using createimagefromstring(), returns a resized (resampled) image for display:

```
$max_width = 170;

// Get the image

@mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass');
@mysql_select_db('db');

$query = "SELECT `thumbnail_contents`, `thumbnail_mimetype` FROM `videos` WHERE video_number  = '$video_number'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_object($result);

// Resize if pic bigger than $max_width
// Set the header
header('Content-type:' . $row->thumbnail_mimetype);

// Get original size of image
$image = imagecreatefromstring($row->thumbnail_contents);
$current_width = imagesx($image);
$current_height = imagesy($image);

// Set thumbnail width
$widths = array($current_width, $max_width);
$new_width = min($widths);

// Calculate thumbnail height from given width to maintain ratio
$new_height = $current_height / $current_width*$new_width;

// Create new image using thumbnail sizes
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width,$new_height);

// Copy original image to thumbnail
imagecopyresampled($thumb,$image,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,imagesx($image),imagesy($image));

// Show thumbnail on screen
$show = imagejpeg($thumb);

// Clean memory
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($thumb);
```

Currently, this script works for most thumbnails and shows them on-screen as desired.  However, when I upload an image with a high width, say over 1000px, it gets stored in the database, but the script doesn't show the resampled image.

To troubleshoot, I've checked the db, as well as print_r'd the output from the query.  Everything seems to be kosher...  Could someone tell me what might be causing such behavior?  Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$5 says php is running out of memory.  Check your php error logs.